# How do I update on object from two different views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have an image that has a shared categories parameter. Right now it's functioning just how I'd like when I create or edit that image within a modal. It uses several js.erb partials to call new, create, edit and update.

I'd like to also have the ability to update the categories on the image show page by clicking a checkbox and have the update occur using ajax immediately without pushing a button.
Most of this works for me too. If I click on the checkbox and press the button to update it does, going through the update action in the controller. My CoffeeScript is written that if put a check in one of the boxes and I have it set to console.log or alert("whatever") it will. What I need to do is figure out how to connect these two, without using the `update.js.erb` and `edit.js.erb` I used before because they one triggers opening a modal the other triggers closing it. Neither of these are unnecessary in this circumstance.

What I can't wrap my head around is since I am already using the update and edit actions how do I call them to do the new thing, update with rendering anything?

I figured a could create additional image paths in routes and new actions in the controller. Since I'm not really sure if this is the correct way to go I tried trying to find tutorials or blog posts online that might cover this subject, but I haven't gotten anywhere yet.

Does anyone know how to do what I am trying to figure out?
Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit Added Code and a better attempt at a description:**

This is my code for the update action that starts in index. A link is used to call edit.js.erb, which calls edit.html.erb, which renders a form partial. After hit submit to update. update.js.erb is called closing the modal, saving the update and rendering the update on the original index page. I like this it works how i want:

ImageController

```
...

 def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @categories = current_user.categories.all
  end

  def update
    @image.update(image_params)
      redirect_to user_images_url(current_user), notice: 'Image Updated'
  end

  private
def image_params
   params.require(:image).permit(:file, :start_at, :end_at, category_ids: [])
end
```

edit.js.erb

```
$("#image-modal").html("<%= j render 'edit' %>")
$("#image-modal").modal("show")
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

images/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for shallow_args(current_user, @image) do |f| %>


<%= f.label :category_ids, "Categories" %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :category_ids,  current_user.categories.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>

<%= f.file_field :file, class: "fileinput-new" %>

<%= f.button :submit, "Add" %><br>
<%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
```

update.js.erb

```
$("#images_<%= @image.id %>").replaceWith("<%= j render @image %>").preventDefault()
$("#image-modal").modal("hide")
```

This is the code that confuses me. On the @image show page their is a collection of the categories associated with the user/owner of the image and all the categories that the user has created, whether they are currently associated with this image or not. The categories that are associated with this image have check marks in their checkboxes, the others do not. If I put a check in a different checkbox and press submit, it updates like a normal form without ajax associated, reloading the entire page. I'd like to make it that when I put a check in an unchecked box or uncheck a checked box it will immediatly update the database without having to press the update button. I've used update.js.erb and edit.js.erb to to update my image from the index page, so I can't use them to update my image from the show page([tutorials tell me to use them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk&t=625s)). The jquery behavior from the show page for update is very different from jquery for update from the index page.

The bit about my coffeescript is to demonstrate that the .click script works, so my issue isn't with that part.

I hope this is clearer.

images/show.html.erb

```
<div class="image-show">

    <%= image_tag(@image.file_url(:show).to_s) %>

</div>

<div id="category-list">
    <%= simple_form_for shallow_args(current_user, @image), remote: true do |f| %>

        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids,  current_user.categories.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Add" %><br>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

images.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('.edit_image input[type=submit]').remove()
  $('.edit_image input[type=checkbox]').click ->
    $(this).parent('form').submit()
    return
```

Comment: You need to add the code in the question. Otherwise we are just guessing. My 2c is only use `js.erb` if you really have to use the rails templating system. If you are stuffing a bunch of client side logic into `js.erb` templates you get this brittle soup where rails suddenly is responsible for maintaining state in the client side. Which is just plain wrong.

Comment: Your question is really hard to read and understand. please try to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, I just added code and tried to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was way off on what the problem was in the first place.

The short version of my solution is that when I was calling `.parent('form')` on my `.edit_image` click event, it was not able to find the `form` on the DOM for a reason I'm not completely sure about to this point. `$(this).closest('form).submit()` was able to find the `form` on the DOM and I was able to successfully add and remove categories to my image without having to reload the page.

A few other issues that may have effected my outcome, is my `update` method in `ImagesController` did not have a `respond_to` for `format.js` and I changed `@image.update(image_params)` to `@image.update_attributes!(image_params`). I also removed my `shallow_args` helper method, that determines whether this is a new instance of an item or an editing of an old instance on my shared forms, since this was only going to be a form for editing.

Final pertinent code:

ImageController

```
def update
  @image.update_attributes!(image_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to user_images_url(current_user), notice: 'Image Updated' }
    format.js
  end
```

images/show.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @image, remote: true do |f| %>

        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids,  current_user.categories.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Add" %><br>
    <% end %>
```

images.coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('.edit_image input[type=submit]').remove()
$ ->
  $('.edit_image input[type=checkbox]').click ->
    $(this).closest('form').submit()
    return
```